# How to ensure values are populated in the variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, meteor

How can I put an *if* statement that checks that my variables are populated? My code works fine but I want to put these checks in place in the case the values are not retrieved from the database. I can then handle things accordingly.

Thank you in advance for having a look

```
var thisFunction = function(callback) {
  var valueToRetrieve = Meteor.user().profile.temp.valOne
  var valueToRetrieveAsWell = Meteor.user().profile.temp.valOne
  callback(null, {a: valueToRetrieve, b: valueToRetrieveAsWell})
}

var thisFunctionSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(thisFunction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (valueToRetrieveAsWell != undefined) { }
or
if (typeof valueToRetrieveAsWell !== "undefined") { }
```

Answer (score -1):

This?? I'm not exactly sure what your asking for

```
if(!variabe){ //no variable
//run some code
}else{
//if there is a variable run more code
}
```